# Select drop down from associated model

Tags: cakephp, model, drop-down-menu

I have a model InstrumentFunding (id,title) that belongsTo InstrumentFundingGroup (id,title)

In the backend when I add/edit the InstrumentFunding I want a select dropdown to select the InstrumentFundingGroup

I tried using `$form->input('InstrumentFundingGroup',array('type' => 'select'));` but the dropdown is empty

How can I do this?

Comment: tip: use cake bake script to bake your controller, model and most importantly views. this way you learn a lot - especially how those related lists end up in the select boxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller:

```
$instrumentFundingGroups = $this->InstrumentFundingGroup->find( 'list' );
$this->set( compact( 'instrumentFundingGroups' ) );
```

In your view:

```
$form->input('InstrumentFundingGroup.id' );
```

Cake does the work of recognizing that the array identified by the pluralized model name should populate the id field for that model. Check out the [automagic form fields](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1390/Automagic-Form-Elements) page in the docs. Those outline what's happening.

Comment: The $form->input('InstrumentFundingGroup.id' ); doen't output anything. But when I pr($instrumentFundingGroups); in my view I get the correct array